# Issue with passport module in Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

i am trying to use passport in my Node js Login system which is working with mongodb.
I have included both passport module and Local strategy in my app.js file.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator=require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var session= require("express-session");
var passport=require("passport");
var LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer=require("multer");
var flash=require('connect-flash');
var mongo=require('mongodb');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var db=mongoose.connection;
```

In users  route file i have declared users

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport=require("passport");
var LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User=require('../models/users');
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('register',{
      "title":'Register'
    });

});
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login',{
        "title":'Login'
    });

});
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
    //get the form values
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email= req.body.email;
    var username= req.body.username;
    var password= req.body.password;
    var password2= req.body.password2;


//Check for image filed
if(req.files&&req.files.profileimage){
    console.log('Uploading file....');
    //File Info
    var profileimageoriginalname =req.files.profileimage.originalname;
    var profileimagename=req.files.profileimage.name;
    var profileimageMime=req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
    var profileimagePath=req.files.profileimage.path;
    var profileimageExt=req.files.profileimage.extension;
    var profileimageSize=req.files.profileimage.size;

}else{
    //Set a default image
    var profileimageName="noimage.png";

}
//Form Validation
req.checkBody('name',"nAME FILED IS REquiered").notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email',"email FILED IS REquiered").isEmail();

req.checkBody('username',"UsernamenAME FILED IS REquiered").notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password',"password FILED IS REquiered").notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password2',"password font marchjFILED IS REquiered").equals(req.body.password);
//Check for errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
        res.render('register',{
            errors:errors,
            name:name,
            email:email,
            username:username,
            password:password,
            password2:password2
        });

    }else{
        var newUser=new User({
            name:name,
            email:email,
            username:username,
            password:password,
            profileimage:profileimagename


        });
        //Create user
        User.createUser(newUser,function(err,user){
            if(err)throw err;
            console.log(user);

        });
        //Sucess message
        req.flash('success',"You are now registered and may login");
        res.location('/');
        res.redirect('/');
    }

});
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    User.getUserbyId(id,function(err,user){
        done(err,user);
    });
});
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username,password,done){
User.getUserByUsername(username,function(err,user){
  if(err) throw  err;
  if(!user){
      console.log("Unknown user");
      return done(null,false,{message:"unknown user"});
  }
  User.comparePassword(password,user.password,function(err,isMatch){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch){
          return done(null,user);
      }else{
          console.log("invalid password");
          return done(null,false,{message:"invalid passwors"});
      }
  });

});
}
));

router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local',{failureRedirect:"/users/login/",failureFlash:"Wrong login or pass"}),function(req,res){
console.log("Authentication Successfully done");
req.flash('success',"You are loged in");
res.redirect('/');
});
module.exports = router;
```

And also i have created a module for my users login

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var bcrypt=require('bcrypt');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeAuth', { useMongoClient: true });
var db=mongoose.connection;

//User scheme
var UserSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    usernam:{
        type:String,
        index:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,required:true,bcrypt:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String
    },
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    profileimage:{
        type:String
    }


});
var User=module.exports=mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
module.exports.comparePassword=function(candidatePassword,hash,callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword,hash,function(err,isMatch){
        if(err) return callback(err);
        callback(null,isMatch);
    });
}

module.exports.getUserById=function(id,callback){

        User.findById(id,callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername=function(username,callback){
    var query={username:username};
    User.findOne(query,callback);
}

module.exports.createUser=function(newUser,callback){
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, 10,function(err,hash){
if(err)throw err;
//Set hashed password
        newUser.password=hash;
        //create User
        newUser.save(callback)
    });
```

}

But its'nt returning aboslutely nothing.
COuld anyone help?
I think it's mostly connected with passport module,but also i have absolutely nor errrors which i can debug.
I mongodb it's showing the whole of my databases.I am trying to log in with my login which is previously registered in my database and works fine but its'nt returning nothing.It's just refrashing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your schema:

```
//User scheme
var UserSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    usernam:{
        type:String,
        index:true
    },
...
```

It should be "usernamE" :)